# Cannot search in "settings" on one computer, but can on another

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

When using the start menu -> settings app, typing "programs" in the "Find a setting" search box will display 14 search results on my stationary computer.

On a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop, it doesnt matter whatever I write in that box, no search results at all.

Why?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: The Search indexer might not have indexed that part?

Comment: So settings are not automatically searchable?